MUI 5/6 border radius is different in default settings and when used with theme.shape.borderRadius
I am using Mui for my website and while constructing theme, I set my border radius to be
{
    palette: ...,
    shadows: ...,
    typography: ...,
    shape: {
      borderRadius: 3,
    },
  }

Now, when I import Button from MUI directly and use the buttton, it has border radius 3px checked in Chrome inspect. I have created another box using the theme.shape.borderRadius, and it is more rounded, having a border radius of 9px.
Why are the border radii different even though they should be referring to the same value I set in the theme?
<Button
  variant="contained"
    sx={{
     width: "100px",
     height: "36px",
     color: "black",
     backgroundColor: "white",
    }}
>
 Start now
</Button>
<Box
 sx={{
  width: "100px",
  height: "36px",
  color: "black",
  backgroundColor: "white",
  borderRadius: (theme) => theme.shape.borderRadius,

  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
  }}
 >
  Start now
</Box>

Settings px explicity works, but that's not what I want to do.
borderRadius: (theme) => theme.shape.borderRadius+'px'

theme.shape.borderRadius specifies the default border radius value (in pixels)
The prop borderRadius, that is passed to components, tells by how much the theme border radius will be multiplied
If a component receives borderRadius as number, it multiplies it by theme.shape.borderRadius
In your example, your theme border radius is 3 and the Box border radius is also 3 as number (since it returns the theme's one) and that leads to 3x3=9px
If you want to use the theme border radius, you can simply pass 1 as value
<Box borderRadius={1} /> This tells mui that you want to use the theme border as it is, without the need of a callback to access the theme
Here in this example they have a comment that says theme.shape.borderRadius * 1

Ah, thanks. This makes sense. Thanks for the help.
